# How to place an order using Magento2 API?

Tags: api, rest, magento2

I am looking for the complete "happy path" to place an order using Magento2's REST API. So far these are all the steps I have followed. What else am I missing?

1. Create a user: `[POST] /rest/V1/customers`
2. Log In (create a token): `[POST] /rest/V1/integration/customer/token`
3. Get Product Categories for navigation: `[GET] /rest/V1/categories`
4. Get Products:

   4.1 Get Category Products: `[GET] /rest/V1/categories/{category_id}/products`

   4.2 Or search for a product: `[GET] /rest/V1/products`
5. Create a cart: `[POST] /rest/V1/carts/mine`
6. Add items to cart: `[POST] /rest/V1/carts/mine/items`
7. Get cart payment information `[GET] /rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information`
8. ...

What other things do I have to do to place the order?

Comment: Did you take this a step further and create a shipment for an order as well? I can't seem to figure out how to POST the right parameters to create a shipment. I can edit existing ones, but can't create new ones. Curious to see if you've figure it out.

Comment: Sorry I did not. I only sell virtual products.

Answer (score 4):

1. create empty cart
   url : http://www.xxxxxx.com/rest/V1/carts/mine
   call: post
   response: cartID eg: 4290
2. Add item to the cart
   url : http://www.xxxxxx.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/items
   body:

   ```
   {"cartItem":{
     "sku":"JFCO00017","qty":1,"name":"Devil May Cry III 3 Dante           Cosplay           Costume","price":81.55,"product_type":"simple","quote_id":"4290","product_option":{"extension_attributes":{"custom_options":[{"option_id":"thumbnail","option_value":"\/d\/e\/devilmaycryiii3dantecosplay_1_.jpg"},{"option_id":"color_2","option_value":"Red"},{"option_id":"google_size","option_value":"xxs"}]}}}
   }
   ```
3. Add billling info
   url : http://www.xxxxxx.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/billing-address
   body:

   ```
   {
   "address": {
   "city": "noida",
   "company": "iprag",
   "countryId": "IN",
   "email": "manish+2@gmail.com",
   "firstname": "Manish",
   "lastname": "Kumar",
   "postcode": "201301",
   "region": "UP",
   "saveInAddressBook": 1,
   "street": ["D-84"],
   "telephone": "8802xxxx90"
   },
   "useForShipping": true
   }
   ```
4. get shipping-methods
   url : http://www.xxxxxx.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-methods

   ```
   {
   "carrier_code": "flatrate",
   "method_code": "flatrate",
   "carrier_title": "Flat Rate",
   "method_title": "Fixed",
   "amount": 10,
   "base_amount": 10,
   "available": true,
   "error_message": "",
   "price_excl_tax": 10,
   "price_incl_tax": 10
   ```

   }
5. add shipping info
   url : http://www.xxxxxx.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information
   body:

   ```
   {
    "addressInformation": {
    "billingAddress": {
       "city": "noida",
       "company": "iprag",
       "email": "nkn@gmail.com",
       "firstname": "Manish",
       "lastname": "Kumar",
       "postcode": "335001",
       "region": "UP",
       "street": ["D-84"],
       "telephone": "9413433217"
   },
   "shippingAddress": {
       "city": "noida",
       "company": "iprag",
       "email": "nkn@gmail.com",
       "firstname": "Manish",
       "lastname": "Kumar",
       "postcode": "335001",
       "region": "UP",
       "street": ["D-84"],
       "telephone": "9413433217"
     },
      "shippingCarrierCode": "flatrate",
     "shippingMethodCode": "flatrate"
   }
   }
   ```

response: payment method and cart detail

5. Order place
   URL : http://www.xxxxxx.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/order
   body :

   ```
   {
    "paymentMethod":{"method":"checkmo"},
    "shippingMethod":
       {
         "method_code":"flatrate",

         "carrier_code":"flatrate",
         "additionalProperties":{}

       }

   }
   ```

response: orderid

Comment: Could  you please answer this question ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158020/not-able-to-place-the-order-using-paypal-in-magento-2-rest

Comment: sure, I have the same issue.

Comment: Step # 4: get shipping-methods.
When performing a GET request as mentioned in magento 2 rest API docs(quoteShippingMethodManagementV1: /V1/carts/mine/shipping-methods) its giving {"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"cartId"}} as a response. There is not required parameter mentioned in documention. Please help!!

Comment: Do i need to pass 'cartId' in place of 'mine' in the every URL??

Comment: And when i perform the last step, where we place order on /V1/carts/mine/order(/V1/carts/{cartId}/order, i replaced 'mine' with cartId otherwise it say cartId is a required field) it responds with '{"message":"Please enter a customer email."}'

Comment: Please verify from the frontend site that customer cart is created before get shipping method call.

Comment: When I am adding billing addres then in response to shipping-methods it is giving error for Shipping address not set.

Comment: could you please share the code you used for all above operations. A BIG help

Comment: I want to place order for Virtual products. I am getting error on Shipping Method. Can anyone assist ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I finally got it right.

8. Save payment information and create order `[POST] /rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information`

Comment: Can you provide more information about the payload here? For instance, how do you set the shipping address?

Comment: how to set shipping address to quote using api?

Comment: I believe there is a previous step (before 8.) but I have not tried it yet because I amy selling virtual products only. Please fix my answer when you do find it so it can help others.

Comment: yeah, there are two way to place order by rest api
 1.[POST] /rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information
 2. [POST] /rest/V1/carts/mine/order

Comment: If I post that one, then I need to set the payment information previously?

Comment: Referring to point 7. you mentioned in your question, when i am performing a [GET] on /rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information, so magento responds me with {"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"cartId"}}. Do i need to pass cartId in place of mine in the URL?? Please help!!