# Magento 2 REST api for PayPal module

Tags: php, angular, magento, paypal, magento2.1

I am creating an eCommerce application using **Magento 2** REST api as backend and **Angular 6** in front-end technology.

I have successfully integrated add/update/delete/list api of **CART**

I am using Paypal for payment methods, after getting a success response from PayPal, I need to store PayPal response to Magento 2 database but it is returning an error.

I need the parameter name of post request.

**ERROR**

```
 "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
"parameters": {
    "fieldName": "cartId",
    "fieldValue": null
}
```

**POST URL**

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information
```

**REQUEST DATA**

```
    {
    "email": "vikram.sharma@xymob.in",
    "cartId": 2,
    "billing_address": {
                    "email": "vikram.sharma@xymob.in",
                "region": "New York",
                "region_id": 43,
                "region_code": "NY",
                    "country_id": "US",
                    "street": ["123 Oak Ave"],
                    "postcode": "10577",
                    "city": "Purchase",
                    "telephone": "512-555-1111",
                    "firstname": "Jane",
                    "lastname": "Doe"
         },
    "paymentMethod": {
        "method": "paypal_express",
        "additional_data": {
            "paypal_express_payment_payload": "{\"id\":\"PAY-3F734824YB370341TLOQNO3Y\",\"intent\":\"sale\",\"state\":\"approved\",\"cart\":\"9W5899822J563802S\",\"create_time\":\"2018-09-18T10:50:31Z\",\"payer\":{\"payment_method\":\"paypal\",\"status\":\"VERIFIED\",\"payer_info\":{\"email\":\"vikramdummy-buyer@outlook.com\",\"first_name\":\"test\",\"middle_name\":\"test\",\"last_name\":\"buyer\",\"payer_id\":\"CAQR5B2LGGB9S\",\"country_code\":\"US\",\"shipping_address\":{\"recipient_name\":\"test buyer\",\"line1\":\"1 Main St\",\"city\":\"San Jose\",\"state\":\"CA\",\"postal_code\":\"95131\",\"country_code\":\"US\"}}},\"transactions\":[{\"amount\":{\"total\":\"102.00\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"details\":{}},\"item_list\":{\"items\":[{\"name\":\"SATA HardDisk\",\"price\":\"1.00\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"quantity\":2},{\"name\":\"Logitech Mouse\",\"price\":\"100.00\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"quantity\":1}]},\"related_resources\":[{\"sale\":{\"id\":\"7CM65242K9229980W\",\"state\":\"completed\",\"payment_mode\":\"INSTANT_TRANSFER\",\"protection_eligibility\":\"ELIGIBLE\",\"parent_payment\":\"PAY-3F734824YB370341TLOQNO3Y\",\"create_time\":\"2018-09-18T10:50:29Z\",\"update_time\":\"2018-09-18T10:50:29Z\",\"amount\":{\"total\":\"102.00\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"details\":{\"subtotal\":\"102.00\"}}}}]}]}",
            "paypal_express_checkout_token": "EC-9W5899822J563802S",
            "paypal_express_checkout_redirect_required": false,
            "paypal_express_checkout_payer_id": "CAQR5B2LGGB9S"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Reference Url

[Rest api for order place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158020/not-able-to-place-the-order-using-paypal-in-magento-2-rest)
  , [Magento swagger](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/)

**Here is my PHP curl code of postman:-**

```
 <?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://127.0.0.1/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n  \"email\": \"vikram.sharma@xymob.in\",\n  \"billing_address\": {\n              \"email\": \"vikram.sharma@xymob.in\",\n              \"region\": \"New York\",\n              \"region_id\": 43,\n              \"region_code\": \"NY\",\n              \"country_id\": \"US\",\n              \"street\": [\"123 Oak Ave\"],\n              \"postcode\": \"10577\",\n              \"city\": \"Purchase\",\n              \"telephone\": \"512-555-1111\",\n              \"firstname\": \"Jane\",\n              \"lastname\": \"Doe\"\n     },\n    \"paymentMethod\": {\n    \"method\": \"paypal_express\",\n    \"additional_data\": {\n      \"paypal_express_payment_payload\": \"{\\\"id\\\":\\\"PAY-3F734824YB370341TLOQNO3Y\\\",\\\"intent\\\":\\\"sale\\\",\\\"state\\\":\\\"approved\\\",\\\"cart\\\":\\\"9W5899822J563802S\\\",\\\"create_time\\\":\\\"2018-09-18T10:50:31Z\\\",\\\"payer\\\":{\\\"payment_method\\\":\\\"paypal\\\",\\\"status\\\":\\\"VERIFIED\\\",\\\"payer_info\\\":{\\\"email\\\":\\\"vikramdummy-buyer@outlook.com\\\",\\\"first_name\\\":\\\"test\\\",\\\"middle_name\\\":\\\"test\\\",\\\"last_name\\\":\\\"buyer\\\",\\\"payer_id\\\":\\\"CAQR5B2LGGB9S\\\",\\\"country_code\\\":\\\"US\\\",\\\"shipping_address\\\":{\\\"recipient_name\\\":\\\"test buyer\\\",\\\"line1\\\":\\\"1 Main St\\\",\\\"city\\\":\\\"San Jose\\\",\\\"state\\\":\\\"CA\\\",\\\"postal_code\\\":\\\"95131\\\",\\\"country_code\\\":\\\"US\\\"}}},\\\"transactions\\\":[{\\\"amount\\\":{\\\"total\\\":\\\"102.00\\\",\\\"currency\\\":\\\"USD\\\",\\\"details\\\":{}},\\\"item_list\\\":{\\\"items\\\":[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"SATA HardDisk\\\",\\\"price\\\":\\\"1.00\\\",\\\"currency\\\":\\\"USD\\\",\\\"quantity\\\":2},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Logitech Mouse\\\",\\\"price\\\":\\\"100.00\\\",\\\"currency\\\":\\\"USD\\\",\\\"quantity\\\":1}]},\\\"related_resources\\\":[{\\\"sale\\\":{\\\"id\\\":\\\"7CM65242K9229980W\\\",\\\"state\\\":\\\"completed\\\",\\\"payment_mode\\\":\\\"INSTANT_TRANSFER\\\",\\\"protection_eligibility\\\":\\\"ELIGIBLE\\\",\\\"parent_payment\\\":\\\"PAY-3F734824YB370341TLOQNO3Y\\\",\\\"create_time\\\":\\\"2018-09-18T10:50:29Z\\\",\\\"update_time\\\":\\\"2018-09-18T10:50:29Z\\\",\\\"amount\\\":{\\\"total\\\":\\\"102.00\\\",\\\"currency\\\":\\\"USD\\\",\\\"details\\\":{\\\"subtotal\\\":\\\"102.00\\\"}}}}]}]}\",\n      \"paypal_express_checkout_token\": \"EC-9W5899822J563802S\",\n      \"paypal_express_checkout_redirect_required\": false,\n      \"paypal_express_checkout_payer_id\": \"CAQR5B2LGGB9S\"\n    }\n  }\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer 1fpiepedxeqm6fse81icfv8yx4hmwbi3",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
    "postman-token: 85951c6b-ff29-b785-65c9-d10c39a34424"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding `email` field in your request data?

Comment: i have updated the request and response please check

Comment: Do you use `POST` operation? Can you put how do you do your call?

Comment: yes i am using post method, and i am using postman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `cartId`, try to use `cart_id`.

If you see the `webapi.xml`, we have :

```
<route url="/V1/carts/mine/payment-information" method="POST">
     <service class="Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentInformationManagementInterface" method="savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder"/>
     <resources>
         <resource ref="self" />
     </resources>
     <data>
         <parameter name="cartId" force="true">%cart_id%</parameter>
     </data>
 </route>
```

The parameter part means that route take a `cart_id` parameter from request and change it to a php parameter called `cartId`.

Comment: I have tried with both parameters, but it doesn't works. Also I am logged in user so we don't need to send the cardId parameter.

Comment: I really don't understand because if I put the parameter `cartId` in my request data, I got the same error than you. If I put `cart_id`, I passed this verification. Do you have any specific module which could override some part of Magento Api code?

Comment: one thing i need to know how to get my posted data in magento controller

Comment: i am totally new in magento i need your help

Comment: Your route go into this model function `src/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php:76`. You can check here if you got your `$cartId` value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180422/discussion-between-sharma-vikram-and-jouby).